# Bluetooth HM-10 PIN to connect, Authentication / Security

Tags: ios, security, authentication, bluetooth, uuid

I am using a HM10 Bluetooth - UART module in my embedded Device. I connect to it via the UUID with an iPhone App, but I would like to activate a PIN to connect for the first time, so that not everybody with an iPhone and a App like LightBlue or something like that, can send data to my device.
Is this somehow possible with the HM10? In the manual is written, that it is possible to use a PIN to pair, but even if I activate this, I didn't need to enter this.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am also using the same adapter (HM-10) or basically CC41-A module, because I have just found out that my module is a clone. I do not know that it could cause authentication issue or not, but I would recommend first identify your module. Do you have also on your board a missing crystal in the position what is shown on this picture:
http://nerdclub-uk.blogspot.com/2016/02/working-with-cheap-bluetooth-btle4.html

If it is missing it is a clone module.

EDITED:
I have just found on that blog in the comments that clone is not supporting authentication.
https://blog.yavilevich.com/2017/03/mlt-bt05-ble-module-a-clone-of-a-clone/

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change the password of the HM-10 Bluetooth Chip. To do this, you can issue an **AT Command**.

Assuming you're using an Arduino environment to interface with your embedded device, you'll want to go to the Serial Monitor found in *Tools  Serial Monitor* and type in the following in the textfield:

```
AT + PASS [YOURPASSWORD]
```

Press enter or send and you should see the following:

```
OK + Set: [para1]
```

You can find more **AT Commands** for the HM-10 chip at http://fab.cba.mit.edu/classes/863.15/doc/tutorials/programming/bluetooth.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already tried this. And I also typed the command AT+TYPE2, to activate "Auth with PIN" as written in the Datasheet. After applying these two commands, I get the question of the PIN to pair the devices, but if I just press cancel, I can communicate, even if I don't enter the PIN, so that is the problem :/. Have anyone tried this before?

Comment: Additional question : Let's say that the remote devices requires a pin to access a given UUID. This pin is only displayed when you try to access it and is random. Will I get prompted to type the pass with those AT commands ? Is there a proper way to manage such a behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Use AT command for set password:

```
AT+PASS?
AT+PASS[parameter]
```

Bond mode (0: not need PIN Code, 1: Auth not need PIN, 2: Auth with PIN, 3: Auth and bond):

```
AT+TYPE?
AT+TYPE[parameter]
```

Important: if your module version is less than V515, please don't use this command.

```
AT+VERR?
```